# How to use sklearn LassoCV, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, lasso-regression

This is hopefully a very simple question for anyone who has used `sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV` successfully.

I'm doing my first Lasso regression on a very simple simulated data set as follows... I'm getting unsatisfactory results and I want to know what it is I'm doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 100)
e = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
# coefficients
b0, b1, b2, b3 = 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3
# target
Y = b0 + b1 * X + b2 * X**2 + b3 * X**3 + e
# the dataset x**1, ..., x**10 
data = pd.DataFrame({"Y":Y, "X1":X})
for i in range(2, 11): data["X{:d}".format(i)] = data["X1"]**i

X = data.drop(axis = 1, labels = 'Y')
Y = data['Y']

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# standardize the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
Xscl = pd.DataFrame( data = scaler.fit_transform(X), columns = ['X'+`i` for i in range(1, 11)] )

# lasso constraints
alphas = np.logspace(-3, 1, 1000)
# perform regression with 10 fold cv
model = LassoCV(alphas = alphas, cv = 10, max_iter=10000, tol=0.0001, eps = 0.0001)
result = model.fit(Xscl, Y)

# reverse scale coefficients and plot fit over data
coeff = model.coef_/scaler.scale_
x1 = np.linspace(0., 10., 100)
pp.plot(X['X1'], Y, 'o')
pp.plot(x1, np.polyval(coeff[::-1], x1), '--')

# print(model.coef_)
# [-6.3122168  
# 38.18296697 
# 30.20713128 
# 16.3567352   
# 7.30950212  
# 2.27074138
# 0.         
# 0.         
# -1.16784659 
# -1.88575215]
```

plotting the fit over the data gives the following. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how 'X'+`i` is not returning an error. And running linear regression on data that is this clearly not linear is not going to return good results no matter what you do.

Comment: @Acccumulation This example is modified from an exercise in the book Introduction to statistical learning so I'd be surprised if the general set up is wrong. In particular, this is a polynomial regression problem and as the relevant Wikipedia page points out -- "although polynomial regression fits a nonlinear model to the data, as a statistical estimation problem it is linear, in the sense that the regression function E(y | x) is linear in the unknown parameters that are estimated from the data"

Comment: @Acccumulation are you referring to `columns = ['X'+\`i\` for i in range(1, 11)]`? notice the apostrophes around the i, which cast the integer to a string.

Comment: Those aren't apostrophes around i, they're grave accent marks. And `i` doesn't cast the *value* of the variable i as a string, it casts the *name* of the variable as a string. For the former, you need str(i).